# Sent a url link with the account information via email

Tags: url, cookies, user-accounts

i am working on a project that sent a URL link  to a user and the user has to put the user account information to log into that account .Is there any way to implement the user account information to that link in order the user won't type every time his account information when he receiving his information?.

Comment: what user account information?

Comment: username and password @MuhammadSumonMollaSelim

Comment: you want so that without entering username and password, user will login only by clicking the link, right?

Comment: yes!@MuhammadSumonMollaSelim

Comment: Thank you very much!@MuhammadSumonMollaSelim

Comment: If it helped, you can accept my answer.

Comment: i tryied but i don't have more than 15 reputation so it doesn't let me vote

Comment: No problem. Keep contributing, you will earn reputation soon.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to generate an unique link and tie it with the user for a specific period of time (for security reason). Then send the link to the user so that he/she can login using that link within that specific period of time. If that time is passed, he/she will need to request a new link.

So here's the step by step breakdown:
1. User inputs his email/phone number.
2. You check on the database if there's any user available for that email/phone number in your database. If user found, you will need to store an unique token for that user and store it.
3. Generate the link with that token.
4. When user click on the link, match the token with your database and user, and if it matches that means user is authorized and let him login. Delete the token.

Let me know if you need any more explanation.